# Hello, I am receiving a json string, I need to separate data by class properties

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I am receiving a json string, I need to separate data by class properties. The problem is that I can only know part of the key. For example, the key is 12345@666.777, I only know @666.777. Is it possible to somehow use regular expressions or look for values by part of the key?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to share an example of what the JSON data looks like, and what output you want? It's hard to understand what you need without that extra information. Apart from that, what approaches have you tried so far? What problems did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate over all the keys in the JSON object as shown here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/iterating-over-json-properties/1940/2

and check for every key if it contains the partial key I have as a substring using this standard Kotlin method:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html

You also need to treat cases where the same substring is present in 2 different keys (if you think that is possible).